undefined ag-grid grand row data
When using a flat table (without any groups etc..) with the newly functionality of ag grid that calculates automatically the total datagrandTotalRow=bottom, we need to get the footer row data. We try the below code
  const footer = this.tableAgGridService.gridAPI.getPinnedBottomRow(0);

but footer is always undefined even there are footer data.
